# Tensorflow Android : retrained Inception v3 take too much time

Tags: android, tensorflow

I have retrained the Inception-V3 final layer with my own 20 categories. When I am using retrained model in android demo app it takes 6 to 8 seconds to predict.

Running on

- LG G4 Stylus  ->  6-8 sec
- S6, ->  3-4.5 sec

I have done `optimize_for_inference` it takes 6-9 sec and `quantize_graph` it takes 7-11 sec. Is there any way to improve it?

Output on LG G4 Stylus:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKryY.png)

**EDIT**

I have followed [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining)

Answer (score 0):

Comparing your debug output to the normal TF Classify app on my phone I see that you have a much larger node count which would suggest that, for some reason, your graph is a lot larger than it should be. I'm not too familiar with the quantize method but it looks like you have more conv2D layers than normal as well.

Without any further information it's hard to say but I think that you should rebuild the graph and check that you've added the final layer properly.

Comment: @JCookr I have tried to retrained the graph and apply optimization but got same results.

Comment: I don't think that you need to only retrain but also re-build the shape. Are you following a tutorial?

Comment: Yes, I have followed [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining) and [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0) .

Comment: can you guide me more?

Comment: I'm not sure how much more I can help. Can I suggest you visualise your graph in Tensorboard and ensure that it is what you expect. Comparing it to the standard inception graph might be a good place to start.

Comment: OK. I'll try that.